# How to COUNT OVER PARTITION BY in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions

What is the pandas equivalent of the window function below

```
COUNT(order_id) OVER(PARTITION BY city)
```

[image]

I can get the row_number or rank

```
df['row_num'] = df.groupby('city').cumcount() + 1
```

But COUNT PARTITION BY city like in the example is what I'm looking for

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) ) and revise your question accordingly. Also [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: bdw looks like you want `df['total_orders']=df.groupby('city')['order_id'].transform('count')`

Comment: May bad about the pic. And thanks for the answer! That worked

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
df['total_orders']=df.groupby('city')['order_id'].transform('count')
```

The "transform" after the groupby, is a call function producing a like-indexed DataFrame on each group and returns a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values.
In this case, you indicate to use the "count(order_if)" aggregation within each "city".
See this for more details:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.